# How to get selected checkbox row data to next page in jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I am new to jQuery DataTables. Currently I am doing insert update and delete operations on a DataTable. When I click on any of checkbox and then if I click on update button I should move to next PHP page (`update.php`) and on that page I should also get all data in respective field. Does anybody know how to do that?

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table= $('#employee_data').dataTable();
        $("#update").click(function() {
            var count = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
            if (count < 1) {
                alert('please select a check box');
            } else {
                //do something
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['update'])) {
    $box = $_GET['num'];
    $count = count($box);
    if ($count == 0){
        header('Location:table.php');
    }elseif($count == 1){
        foreach($_GET['num'] as $id) {
            header("Location:update.php?id=".$id);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: can u show your  html ?

Comment: You need to get all the IDs of the rows that are selected and send them to the next page. With you using $_GET I'm guessing you'll want to pass an array of IDs as some sort of URL-encoded variable. Something like `?id=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%5D` which can be decoded by the receiving PHP script and manipulated.

Comment: How to pass id of selected row data to next page                                <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table= $('#employee_data').dataTable();
        $("#update").click(function() {
            var count = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
            if (count == 1) {
                window.location ='update.php';
            } else {
                window.location='table.php';
            }
        });
    });
</script>

Comment: Use the Select extension to help you here.  https://datatables.net/extensions/select/    It will help you manage your selected items, get your selected rows from the grid, ..etc.  Then yes you need to transmit your data to the next page as those above me have pointed out.